# Why does Matlab factorial function perceives an integer as a non-integer?

Tags: matlab, integer, factorial

I'm trying to build a function in Matlab which generates a Taylor series around 0 for sine and the user can insert x (the value for which the sine is approximated) and a maximum error. Thus I want the function to check the maximum error and from this maximum it generates the amount of elements in the Taylor series.

I get the following error:

> Error using factorial (line 20)
>
> N must be an array of real non-negative integers.
>
> Error in maxError (line 19)
>
> y(x) = y(x) + (-1)^(j) * x^(2j+1)/factorial(2j+1)

Below my code.

```
function [n] = maxError(x,e);
%Computes number of iterations needed for a given absolute error.

n=1;

while abs(x)^(n+1)/factorial(n+1) >= e
    n = n+1;
end


if mod(n,2) == 0
    n=n+1;
end

y=@(x) x;

j=1;
while j<n
    y(x) = y(x) + (-1)^(j) * x^(2j+1)/factorial(2j+1)
    j=j+1;
end

return
```

I think I get the error because the `factorial` function can only take up integers, but the way I see it, I am feeding it an integer. Since `j=1;`  and then gets larger by one per iteration, I don't see how Matlab can perceive this as something else than a integer.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The initial value for j=1 sure is an integer, but while iterating through the while loop is there no way it becomes a float? Do you think adding a `print(j)` after updating its value `j=j+1` would help you figure the numbers that are being passed and ensure it's always an integer?
Also you solve this by adding an `if j is int` clause that skips the while loop when this condition is not met. Sorry for the language, I only tried matlab once

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `j` as an indexing variable, which is also the complex number in Matlab, and your are forgetting a `*` multiply.

You can use `j` as a variable (not recommended!) but when you are putting a number in front of it, Matlab will stil interpret is as the complex number, and not as the variable.

Adding the multiplication symbol will solve the issue, but using `i` and `j` as variables will give you these hard to debug errors. If you had used `a`, the error would have been easier to understand:

```
>> a=10;
>> 2a+1
 2a+1
  ↑
Error: Invalid expression. Check for missing multiplication operator, missing or 
unbalanced delimiters, or other syntax error. To construct matrices, use brackets
instead of parentheses.
```